# Need Help in Oracle/Postgresql Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

Here is a requirement, I hope you can help me in this.

### Requirement :

I need to get the last conversation between sender and receiver and vice versa.

In detail, I have below data in table.

```
    sen | rec |            day             |  msg  
    -----+-----+----------------------------+-------
    A   | B   | 2014-12-05 11:51:38.213723 | HI
    B   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:51:54.486329 | HELLO
    A   | B   | 2014-12-05 11:52:10.289694 | HwRU
    B   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:52:21.613091 | FINE
    A   | C   | 2014-12-05 11:52:32.608677 | HI
    C   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:53:00.695742 | HELLO
    C   | D   | 2014-12-05 11:53:10.058141 | HELLO
    E   | D   | 2014-12-05 11:53:17.473893 | HELLO
    D   | E   | 2014-12-05 11:53:53.675839 | HI
```

Note : The conversation is regardless of sender and receiver .

So, the last conversation between A to B is

```
    B   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:52:21.613091 | FINE
```

the last conversation between A and C is

```
    C   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:53:00.695742 | HELLO
```

like that I need the last conversation between two persons regarless of sender and receiver.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate the the `(sen,rec)` combination without considering the ordering, you can use `least(sen,rec), greatest(sen,rec)` this can be used to group the data and then use the latest row for that using a window function:

```
select sen, rec, day, msg
from (
  select sen, rec, day, msg,
         row_number() over (partition by least(sen,rec), greatest(sen,rec) order by day desc) as rn
  from conversations
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE sendrecv(
    sen CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    , rec CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    , zday TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    , msg varchar
      , PRIMARY KEY(sen,rec,zday)  -- this will cause an index to be created
      , UNIQUE(rec, sen,zday)      -- this will create the "swapped" index
        );

    INSERT INTO sendrecv(sen , rec , zday, msg) values
    ('A', 'B', '2014-12-05 11:51:38.213723', 'HI' )
    ,('B', 'A', '2014-12-05 11:51:54.486329', 'HELLO' )
    ,('A', 'B', '2014-12-05 11:52:10.289694', 'HwRU' )
    ,('B', 'A', '2014-12-05 11:52:21.613091', 'FINE' )
    ,('A', 'C', '2014-12-05 11:52:32.608677', 'HI' )
    ,('C', 'A', '2014-12-05 11:53:00.695742', 'HELLO' )
    ,('C', 'D', '2014-12-05 11:53:10.058141', 'HELLO' )
    ,('E', 'D', '2014-12-05 11:53:17.473893', 'HELLO' )
    ,('D', 'E', '2014-12-05 11:53:53.675839', 'HI' )
        ;
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM sendrecv sr
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM sendrecv nx
        WHERE nx.sen = sr.sen AND nx.rec = sr.rec
        AND nx.zday > sr.zday
        )
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM sendrecv nx
        WHERE nx.sen = sr.rec AND nx.rec = sr.sen
        AND nx.zday > sr.zday
        )
        ;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
 sen | rec |            zday            |  msg  
-----+-----+----------------------------+-------
 B   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:52:21.613091 | FINE
 C   | A   | 2014-12-05 11:53:00.695742 | HELLO
 C   | D   | 2014-12-05 11:53:10.058141 | HELLO
 D   | E   | 2014-12-05 11:53:53.675839 | HI
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last conversation between particular two persons (for example 'A' and 'B'), the solution is quite simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM conversations
WHERE 'A' IN (sen, rec) AND 'B' IN (sen, rec)
ORDER BY "day" DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

For the purpose of finding the last conversations between any two parties the previous two solutions posted will work but I'll give you one more suggestion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (LEAST(sen, rec), GREATEST(sen, rec)) *
FROM conversations
ORDER BY LEAST(sen, rec), GREATEST(sen, rec), "day" DESC;
```

The above statements are written for PostgreSQL.

Comment: `distinct on` will be more efficient than a solution with window functions in Postgres, but will not work in Oracle (nor will the `LIMIT 1`) solution